# Combobox SelectionChangeCommitted event doesn't work with arrow keys

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a combobox with the the property `DropDownList` that runs some code on `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. It works fine with mouse-click but if I try to select using arrow keys it fires after the first key press. How do I get this to work as a standard drop-down that I can navigate with mouse and keys?

```
private void dd_jobs_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Pk_Error p = new Pk_Error(ref_num, j[dd_jobs.SelectedIndex]);
  p.Show(); p.BringToFront();
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I understand that you're talking about navigation through the items when the list is dropped down?

Comment: Yes. Or being able to select items with the keyboard alone without clicking the drop down arrow. Am i using the wrong kind of form element?

Comment: Why you can't use SelectedIndexChanged event instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to adhere to 508 compliance.  I had to implement a combobox that inherits from the windows one and override the functionality.

For you capture the selected text in the OnEnter call and use that during the OnLeave to make the change.  Override the OnSelectionChangeCommitted to check if the list is dropped and not make a selection.

```
            if(this.DroppedDown == true)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted (e);
            sCurrentItem = this.Text;
        }
```